# How to pass variable from orchestration into minion state?

Tags: salt-stack

The test.sls is the state file I call via orchestrate and give the env variable via pillar. How can I get the env value and passing it to web_check sls file.

**test.sls**

```
{% set env = salt.pillar.get('env') %}


{{ env }}_check:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: 'minion-id'
    - sls: web_check     # called sls state file
```

**web_check.sls**

```
{% if env == 'qa' %}

test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ls -ltra /tmp

{% elif env == 'uat' %}

test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ls -ltra /tmp/uat

{% endif %}
```

**Execution**

```
salt-run state.orchestrate test pillar='{"env": "qa"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillar is usually the best way to pass data from orchestration:

```yaml
{% set env = pillar["env"] %}  # the value from the master's pillar (via CLI)

{{ env }}_check:
  salt.state:
    - tgt: minion-id
    - sls: web_check
    - pillar:
        env: "{{ env }}"  # overrides the minion's pillar
```

```yaml
{% if pillar["env"] == "qa" %}

test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ls -ltra /tmp

{% elif pillar["env"] == "uat" %}

test:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ls -ltra /tmp/uat

{% endif %}
```

However, what you're doing here looks exactly like what [Salt Environments](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/top.html#multiple-environments) are for, which you would use the `saltenv` parameter to select.

Comment: can I accomplish what I need without using Master's Pillar?

Comment: @Megazord yes, for example with environments. But using the master's pillar is the part you already had. If it was supposed to be the minion's pillar, then there's no need to pass anything at all.